# Convert 'char' to enum in initialization

Tags: c++11, enums

I am trying to use `enum class`, but finding difficulties converting from other types that have logical correspondence to the enumeration. Here's an example:

```
enum class ElementType {
    unknown,
    signedInt
};

struct VectorType {
    int vectorSize;
    ElementType elementType;
    int elementSize;
}
```

I want to be able to initialize a `VectorType` by saying

```
VectorType vt {4, 's', 32};
```

So I tried defining a cast operation from char to the enum like so:

```
operator ElementType(char c) {
    switch (c) {
    case 's': return ElementType::signedInt;
    default : return ElementType::unknown;
    }
}
```

But that didn't work, as it gives the following error:

```
error: ‘operator ElementType(char)’ must be a nonstatic member function
```

So the only solution I can come up with is create a separate constructor:

```
VectorType(int vsz, char etp, int esz) {
    vectorSize = vsz;
    elementType = make_elementType(etp);
    elementSize = esz;
}
```

and have the global non-member make_elementType() function deal with the conversion. Is there a way to avoid this, i.e. is there a way to use `VectorType vt {4, 's', 32};` to initialize a `VectorType`?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably define the enumerated values:

```
enum class ElementType : char {
    unknown = 'u',
    signedInt = 's'
};
```

The `class` keyword adds scope protection and removes implicit conversion of values; you can't separate the two features. If you want to write in this modern style, the best way is to explicitly cast in the initialization:

```
VectorType vt {4, static_cast< ElementType >( 's' ), 32};
```

Or, being a bit looser with a C-style cast,

```
VectorType vt {4, (ElementType) 's', 32};
```

Comment: I didn't know that! Thanks. I created a constructor taking char as the second argument, and then using a static_cast<ElementType> to convert the argument to ElementType. I can still call it as `VectorType vt {4, 's', 32};`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
VectorType vt {4, ElementType::signedInt, 32};
```

Or, use a plain `enum`

```
enum ElementType {
    unknown,
    signedInt
};
```

then say

```
VectorType vt {4, signedInt, 32};
```

An `enum class` is specifically designed to not allow implicit conversions. I can't see how you would expect some automatic conversion from a `char` to your `ElementType` anyway.

If you definitely need such a mapping, e.g. to convert from user input, you could use an `std::map<char, ElementType>` but that's absolutely contrary to the philosophy of `enum`s.

As for your `operator ElementType(char c)`, like the compiler says, such a conversion operator is only allowed as a member of a `class` and not for built-in types like `char`.

Comment: In the context of the program `ElementType` and `char` are related by a one-to-one mapping as a part of a parser. Maybe ideally, the parser would abstract away the mapping, but it is still convenient to print a VectorType as 4s32, e.g.

Comment: @stanm Conceptually, yes; but you wouldn't want a run-time computation to do the mapping just for style. Unless `'c'` comes from user input, which you could say in your question. In this case, see my edited answer related to `std::map`.